# How to group data by the values of a column? [R]

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe like this:

```
ID RNA pathway
id1 rna1 pathway1
id1 rna5 pathway2
id2 rna2 pathway2
id2 rna2 pathway3
id3 rna3 pathway1
id3 rna3 pathway3
id4 rna17 pathway3
```

And so on. What I would like to do is take the values from the third (pathway) column, and make each unique value into a new column in a new dataframe, then fill up those columns with the corresponding ID's from the first dataframe. The goal is to from a group from each pathway, something like this.

```
pathway1 pathway2 pathway3 ... pathwayN
id1      id1      id2          id3
id3      id7      id56         id8
```

I've tried solving the problem with dcast from the reshape2 package - that way I know whether an ID belongs to a pathway or not, but I cannot gather them into separate groups.

The code so far:

```
library("dplyr")
library("reshape2")
df<-read.table("~/data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
df2<-dcast(df, pathway ~ id)
df2
```

Comment: Can you please also show how the result should look?

Comment: can you please post your code so far?

Comment: I just updated it! Should have done it to begin with, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Your desired output is unclear. Why `pathway1` gets `id3`, for example?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the desired output didn't match the original dataframe.
The point I wanted to make is that any number of ID's can (should) get matched to the columns in the new dataframe

Comment: Still not sure regarding desired output, maybe this? `library(data.table) ;  setDT(df)[, indx := seq_len(.N), by = pathway]; dcast(df, indx ~ pathway, value.var = "ID")`

Comment: Or using Hadleywerse `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);df %>% select(-RNA) %>% group_by(pathway) %>% mutate(indx = row_number()) %>% spread(pathway, ID)`

Comment: Should each ID appear once and only once in each pathway column? And if so, then the resulting columns may have different (non-NA) lengths, correct?

Comment: exactly! This has been my biggest problem so far, the columns are probably going to differ in length

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
(res <- dcast(df, ID ~ pathway, fill=NA, value.var = "ID", id.var="pathway")[,-1])
#   pathway1 pathway2 pathway3
# 1      id1      id1     <NA>
# 2     <NA>      id2      id2
# 3      id3     <NA>      id3
# 4     <NA>     <NA>      id4
```

The `[,-1]` is just to remove the "ID" column at the end.  Each row corresponds to an ID.  If you wanted to collapse the result so all the NAs are at the end of each column, and rows containing NAs are removed, you could do

```
cleaned <- do.call(cbind, lapply(res, sort, na.last=T))
data.frame(cleaned[rowSums(!is.na(cleaned))>0, ])
#      pathway1 pathway2 pathway3
# [1,] "id1"    "id1"    "id2"   
# [2,] "id3"    "id2"    "id3"   
# [3,] NA       NA       "id4"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems cumbersome so hopefully someone can figure out a simpler solution:

```
> ListOfColumns = lapply(unique(data$pathway), function(x) {df = data.frame(unique(data[pathway == x, ]$ID)); names(df) = x; df})
> ListOfColumns
[[1]]
  pathway1
1      id1

[[2]]
  pathway2
1      id2

[[3]]
  pathway3
1      id3
2      id4
```

Now make sure all columns are of the same length, then combine them all:

```
> Rows = do.call(max, lapply(ListOfColumns, nrow))
> ListOfColumns = lapply(ListOfColumns, function(x) x[1:Rows, ,drop = F])
> do.call(cbind, ListOfColumns)
   pathway1 pathway2 pathway3
1       id1      id2      id3
NA     <NA>     <NA>      id4
```